# Microscopes in space?

Tags: crewed-spaceflight, rovers, robotic-missions, microscope

There are a lot of telescopes in space (optical, radio, X-ray and Gamma-ray), but how about *microscopes?*

Does the ISS have a general-purpose microscope? It could come in handy for failure analysis or even some medical tests.

Any robotic-mission microscopes for looking at rocks or particles or micrometeorites, impacts, or space-dust?

Comment: MER certainly had a [microscopic imager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opportunity_(rover)#Design_and_construction), is that what you're looking for?

Comment: @Edlothiad if you can find some information on the maximum magnification (microns per pixel, pixels per millimeter, or something similar) and you can make a case that it is more than just camera than happens to focus at short range, then that would be great!

Comment: An [answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/30397/12102) to a different question also happens to include a discussion of some optical microscopes.

Comment: This [answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/48384/28249) includes two examples of robotic-mission non-optical microscopes, if that is helpful.  I imagine quite a few Mars missions also included optical microscopes.

Comment: @IronEagle thanks! Mars Hand Lens Imager (MAHLI) on Curiosity is mentioned [here](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/25786/12102), I don't know what the Insight lander or Perseverance rover have.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple, at least, on the ISS.

The main one seems to be the [Light Microscopy Module](https://www1.grc.nasa.gov/wp-content/uploads/PS-02052-LMM-Brochure_1016.pdf) (PDF).

> Light Microscopy Module (LMM) is housed within and used in
> conjunction with the glovebox in the Fluids Integrated Rack (FIR).

> Images provided by the LMM can provide data to scientists and
> engineers to help understand the forces that control the organization
> and dynamics of matter at microscopic scales.

> The LMM microscope is
> capable of using most standard Leica objectives. The present on-orbit
> compliment includes: 2.5x,10x, 20x, 40x, 50x, 63x, 63x oil, and 100x
> oil, objectives. New or different objectives may also be flown as
> needed.

> The LMM contains a digital black and white low noise
> scientific camera.   PI specific specialty cells (sample holders) are
> under development for temperature control and electric field
> experiments.   Three dimensional (3D) confocal (point illumination)
> upgrades are scheduled for 2015-2016.

> The Light Microscope Module
> (LMM) flight unit features a modified commercial off-the-shelf (COTS)
> Leica RXA microscope, which is configured to operate in an automated
> mode with some interaction from the ground support staff or the
> astronaut crew. The microscope is modified and enhanced to provide
> additional capabilities including, video microscopy to record sample
> features including basic structures and crystal growth dynamics and
> basic biological system observations.   Currently, demonstrated
> imaging techniques use a high resolution black and white microscopy,
> bright field, epifluorescencent (EPI), and fluorescent techniques.

> An
> investigator can choose from standard Leica objective lenses of
> different magnifications. This suite of measurements enabled by the
> LMM allow for a detailed characterization of fluids, colloids, and
> two-phase media, including biological samples. A backlighting LED
> sample holder was also developed to enhance biological imaging, and is
> available onboard the ISS.

The LMM was recently (May 2017) upgraded with "a laser light package, scanner and two high-resolution digital scientific cameras. In addition to 3D imaging, this update will significantly improve the microscope’s resolution and contrast by eliminating unnecessary light." ([source](https://www.nasa.gov/feature/from-2d-to-3d-space-station-microscope-gets-an-upgrade))

New to me was the [NanoRacks Microscope](http://nanoracks.com/products/microscope/).

> Send us your slides and have ISS crew members take pictures during
> your 30 day mission.

I hope that's not as "name a star after yourself" as it sounds.

Curiosity has a "Hand Lens", the [Mars Hand Lens Imager](https://mars.nasa.gov/msl/mission/instruments/cameras/mahli/).

> The self-focusing, roughly 1.5-inch-wide (4-centimeter-wide) camera
> takes color images of features as small as 12.5 micrometers, smaller
> than the diameter of a human hair.

To me this conjures up images of a robotic Sherlock Holmes peeking through his magnifying glass, so perhaps this is not considered a microscope.

Comment: The LMM sounds very nice indeed, I'll bet it has seen quite a bit of use for a variety of things.

Comment: There's a [new scope](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/41595/12102) in town!

Comment: saw and upvoted, very cool.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to all other mentioned microscopes, there has been a Voxa Mochii miniature scanning electron microscope on the ISS since mid-February 2020.

See [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/41595/32044) for more details.

Answer (score 3):

There are some high-resolution cameras on the Perseverance rover on Mars.

The SHERLOC instrument has a context camera with a resolution of 10.1 micrometres, and the WATSON tool has a colour camera with a resolution of 15 micrometres.  Previous missions also had high-resolution cameras with resolutions up to about 15 micrometres. These resolutions qualify these cameras as "microscopes".

Answer (score 2):

[The Chinese Tiangong Station has one as well](http://www.oeshow.cn/informationdetail/12658):
[image]
[image]

(Translation: microscopic observation and recording equipment for medical samples)